# python не видит cuda на виртуальной машине

Tags: python, pytorch, виртуальная-машина, cuda, nvidia

Питон не использует cuda на виртуалке, хотя все свежие драйверы переброшены, а сама виртуалка видит видеокарту. Использую Hyper-v

Скрин из диспетчера устройств на виртуалке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин вывода команды nvidia-smi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на выполнение кода

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.device_count()
```

мне выводит

```
False
0
```

На хосте python видит видеокарту и может использовать cuda

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Установил pytorch c поддержкой cuda и все заработало